# Virtual hosts apache2 for nette - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apache2, virtualhost

I try run nette framework on Ubuntu 14.04. 
In /etc/hosts i add :`127.0.0.1     example.dev` 
in /etc/apache2/sites-enable/000-default.conf i add:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.dev
  ServerAlias www.example.dev
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/www
  <Directory "/var/www/html/example/www">
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But when i visit example.dev i always see only Apache 2 Ubuntu defalut page. Where is a problem? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'd better create a new vhost configuration file for `example.dev` in `/etc/apache2/site-available/` and name it something like `example.dev.con`. And then enable the site:

```
sudo a2ensite example.dev
```

Reload apache2:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me is: `sudo a2enmod php5`. And now it is correct.